# Hyperledger Composer: Error on network start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start a business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: received trailing metadata size exceeds the limit
Command failed

```
Docker Log for the peer
node-pre-gyp ERR! Completion callback never invoked!
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-144-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/chaincode/output/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /chaincode/output/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
node-pre-gyp ERR!   <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 6
npm ERR! grpc@1.11.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.11.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-10T01_47_37_859Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Your underlying container build failed as grpc failed to build.

- What OS and version?
- Have you followed ALL of the prereqs shown here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs ?
- Also you need to run that prereqs script as a 'normal' user (not sudo or root). Furthermore, when [installing Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) modules you must use npm with `sudo`, `root`,  or `u to root` to use it. I notice in your logs you are using the `root` user.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with versioning. Everything was working fine till yesterday until I updated my bna file. The same box hosts angular application, which must have caused conflicting node versions. I re-did everything on a new AWS server and it works well.

Comment: Is installing composer modules with sudo necessary. I am getting same error while starting network only I installed composer with normal user.